# Redux thunk action is fulfilled when it should have been rejected

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit, redux-thunk

I'm dispatching a thunk action that I expect to be rejected, but it's fulfilled instead...

[image: Edit keen-darwin-i9r53l]

Comment: why it should go to faliur state. you are doing nothing in catch block just thrown an error but in catch block. try something buggy to test this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not returning anything from the thunk, therefore the thunk is considered as fulfilled.

You should `return rejectWithValue(e.message)` in your catch block.

```
} catch (e) {
  errorMessage = `Log from catch block: ${e.message}`;
  return rejectWithValue(e.message);
}
```